# Parsing an array of objects with RapidJSON

Tags: c++, json, file, rapidjson

I'm facing a problem with parsing a JSON file via RapidJSON and loading its contents into attributes of objects which I created in my program (a card game). The JSON file contains two types of Cards - Creature and Spellcards - each of which have attributes assigned to them.

```
bool loadConfig(std::string config_file){

    std::ifstream ifs(config_file);
    rapidjson::IStreamWrapper isw(ifs);
    rapidjson::Document file;
    file.ParseStream(isw);

    assert(file.IsObject());
    assert(file.HasMember("Creatures"));
    assert(file["Creatures"].IsString());
    printf("Name: %s\n", file["Creatures"].GetString());

    return true;
}
```

The function I am working with gets its string from a command line argument. I have tried using IStreamwrapper to get rapidJSON to start parsing, but i am getting the Error Message `"Assertion`file.IsObject()' failed"`.

This is the config file I am working with.

```
{
  "Creatures" : [
    {
      "name": "Big Wall",
      "mana_cost": 7,
      "damage_points": 2,
      "life_points": 9,
      "shield": true,
      "mana_drain": false
    },
    {
      "name": "Werwolf",
      "mana_cost": 13,
      "damage_points": 9,
      "life_points": 6,
      "shield": false,
      "mana_drain": false
    }
  ],
  "Spells" : [
    {
      "name": "Healer"
    },
    {
      "name": "Relief"
    },
    {
      "name": "Rebirth"
    },
    {
      "name": "Dracula"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you check for parse errors with `file.HasParseError()`? If that returns `false`, check the type of `file` with `file.GetType()`

Comment: I just checked and youre right, it has parse errors (GetType also returned null). Could that be because the json has two types of arrays?

Comment: Not sure, but would tell Rapid was In situ ? Maybe you need an char* or char[] to be parsed (version I used few years ago was modifying source memory). https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_stream.html - probably memory stream ? JSON seems to be valid ??

Comment: No need to guess... `cerr << "Parse error " << file.GetParseError() << " at " << file.GetErrorOffset();`

Comment: @Botje i just tried this and it gives me  ```Parse error 1 at 00``` , does this mean i am already working with an invalid config file?

Comment: Error 1 is "kParseErrorDocumentEmpty". What are you passing in for `config_file`? Is `ifs.is_open()` true?

Comment: @Botje So i fixed this now, and now im getting ```Parse error 0 at 03```.

Comment: That would be "kParseErrorNone". Sure you're not parsing an empty object?